# how to get selected/added file count in jQuery MultiFile

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io

I'm using following file input plugin,[jquery multifile plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/)

[image]

I'm trying to get number of files current added selected in jquery multifile plugin

I tried following

```
var filecount = $('#fileinputid')[0].files.length;
```

but this always returns 1

Comment: do you have a working demo somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it,But looked document of it, I think you can use `onFileAppend` event implement for you.

see: [Using events](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/)